# Auto resize subviews on device rotation

Tags: iphone, rotation

I have all my subviews set up so that they are based on `self.view`.

EG: `UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,(self.view.frame.size.width-20),(self.view.frame.size.height-90))];`

however when the view rotates (`shouldRotateToDeviceOrientation` or whatever) the views all stay the same size. How can I make them change shape to fit? Can I do this automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Take a look at the `autoresizingMask` property. If you set your image view, in this case, to have an autoresizing mask of `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`, then when its parent view resizes (as it may or may not automatically do when your app rotates—you might have to set a similar `autoresizingMask` on the parent view), it'll maintain the exterior margins you set up for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have a view in the bottom of parent view this should help:

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Where self is your child view, that should be resized. If you do not set `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`, then in horizontal mode you will not see your view, if it was in the bottom in vertical mode.

Also do not forget to set:

```
self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

And autoresizing modes for all child view in your view. So that when it is resized, everything inside it also gets resized.

Answer (score 0):

you have to `[view setAutoresizingMask:...]`